# Epsilon-delta proof of function limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I need to prove the that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac {x^2}{3-x} = \infty $.

What I've written so far:

The domain of the function is $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{3\}$.
Based on the definition of the limit of a function we need to show that

for every $M > 0$ there is a real number $N$ so that
$x \in X, x < -N \implies \frac{x^2}{3-x} > M$
\
We need to find a real number $N$ that satisfies that condition.

From what I understand, the number $N$ has to be negative? What confuses me is that the condition is true if $N$ would be 2, but 2 is not a negative number. Could someone please explain how the proof continues?

Comment: $N$ has to be positive, actually. $N=2$ is just fine, because you're looking at $x<-N=-2$. However, it doesn't make sense for the condition "to be true" if $N=2$, because you haven't picked a specific $M$ yet

Comment: @Vasili the function is positive when $x<0$

Comment: @FShrike: I did not see that $x$ goes to minus infinity. My bad.

Comment: Applying $\varepsilon-\delta$ method is a torture. Represent the function as ${x^2-9\over 3-x}+{9\over 3-x}=-x-3+{9\over 3-x}.$

Comment: Since the topic in the excercise book is about epsilon-delta proofs, I have to use that one. I figured that since I've written that M>0, then perhaps i can use $\frac{x^2}{3-x}>0$ and then write out N=min{3, M}, but I don't know if thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simplify your inequality first, in analysis always do rough simplifications if available. You don't need to find the perfect epsilon, just one that works.

$3-x$ on the denominator is annoying, what about having a product instead of a subtraction ? It would simplify greatly with the numerator.

And indeed for $x<-3$ (not an issue since $x\to-\infty$) then $2x-x<-3\iff 3-x<-2x$

You then get $$\dfrac{x^2}{3-x}>\dfrac{x^2}{-2x}=-\dfrac x2\to +\infty$$

The espsilon-delta proof for $-x/2$ is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

We need $$\frac{x^2}{3-x} > M \implies \frac{x^2+Mx-3M}{3-x} > 0$$
The last inequality will be true for $x <\frac{-M-\sqrt{M^2+13M}}{2} <3$ so we take $N=\frac{M+\sqrt{M^2+13M}}{2}$ and we guarantee that $\frac{x^2}{3-x} > M$ for $x<-N$